# Disadvantage of GET method in comparison to POST

Tags: http, post, get

What are the Disadvantages of GET method in comparison to POST?  which one is better in case of HTTP Protocol?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is no best HTTP method without considering the task at hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these method is "better" or "worse" they exist for different reasons. The best practices dictate that you use GET to retrieve information/data/pages while POST is for sending your data for the server.

The main difference is in the way the actual data of your request gets to the server. For GET data is assumed to be arguments and is encoded into your address as name=value pairs. For POST name=value pairs go into the body of the message.

One disadvantage GET I can think of is security - if you absolutely want your data to be encrypted you absolutely want POST as only body of the messages can be enchrypted.